# How can I model non-normal latent factors in a factor analysis or SEM?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, path-model

We are running a confirmatory factor analysis (covariance-based SEM form) with three latent variables for around 900 companies. The input is around 20 variables: 5-6 are perfectly normally distributed and the rest is less so with extreme cases of binary and very skewed distributions. Around a third have an IQR of 0.

Even when we restrict the latent variances to 1, we run into severe issues of model fit because the factors are dominated by the normal variables. What are better ways to propagate the non-normal structure into the latent variables? Two solutions we considered are: simple averaging and PLS path modeling.

Comment: There are some approaches to doing this using a mixture model.

Comment: Would you have any pointers @JeremyMiles?

Comment: https://www.statmodel.com/download/usersguide/Mplus%20user%20guide%20Ver_7_r6_web.pdf Example 7.26

Comment: Interesting - it sounds like a hack to use latent classes that are not meaningful to get at non-normality. But if it works... you wouldn't know if there's an R implementation?

Comment: Yep (there are similar hacks to use it to deal with non-linearity). I've never seen an R version. You might be able to do it with openMx.